# I can't figure out how to stop the margin-top from making my child div overflow its parent

Tags: html, css

When I set the child div's margin-top property it always overflows and when I set the parent's position as relative and it's position as absolute it goes off to the side in the middle of the page. Child: menu_button_container, Parent: heading.

I want to move it within the parent div how can I accomplish this?

Css:

```
html, body
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;
}
.heading
{
    width:100%;
    height:20%;
    background-color:green;
}
.content
{
    width:100%;
    height:80%;
    background-color:orange;
}
.menu_button_container
{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top:30%;
    margin-left:0%;
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    height:40%
}
.menu_button
{
    background-color:purple;
    border:none;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    font: 14px;
    color:white;
}
.center_text
{
    width:80%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:blue;
    margin-left: 10%
}
```

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>
    <title>template 1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="project.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="heading">

        <div class="menu_button_container" style="margin-left: 10%">
        <button class="menu_button">Home</button>
        </div>

        <div class="menu_button_container">
        <button class="menu_button">Link</button>
        </div>

        <div class="menu_button_container">
        <button class="menu_button">Link</button>
        </div>

        <div class="menu_button_container">
        <button class="menu_button">Link</button>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <div class="center_text"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I would appreciate any help in this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that's what you want?

```css
body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0px;
}

.heading {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
    background-color: green;
    font-size: 0px;    
}

.menu_button_container {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 80vw;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}

.content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
    background-color: orange;
}

.menu_button {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: purple;
    border: none;
    width: 20vw;
    font: 14px;
    color: white;
}

.center_text {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    margin-left: 10%
}
```

```html
<div class="heading">
<div class="menu_button_container">  
  
<button class="menu_button">Home</button>
<button class="menu_button">Link</button>
<button class="menu_button">Link</button>
<button class="menu_button">Link</button>
  
</div>
</div>

<div class="content">
<div class="center_text">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: updated just right now with `left:0;` `right:0` `margin:auto` on the `menu_button_container` (instead of `margin-left: 10%`);